# lookup username using getactiveuser using Google Spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, lookup, userid

I have been trying to lookup username using activeuser. Only the first part works and the last part doesnt. My goal is to unhide the sheet based on the username of the active user (sheetname is based on username). Below is the code I am using.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Test getActiveUser/getEmail", functionName:  "onTest"});
  ss.addMenu("Rep Drowndown", menuEntries);
  testGetEmail("onOpen");
}


function onTest() {
  testGetEmail("menu function");
};


function testGetEmail(callerId) {
  var userEmail = "";
  var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser();

  if (activeUser == null)
    Browser.msgBox("Session.getActiveUser() returned null", "called by " + callerId, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  else
    userEmail = activeUser.getEmail();

  if (userEmail == "")
    Browser.msgBox("Your Email returned an empty string", "called by " + callerId, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  else
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var lookup = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var range = ss.getRange('$A$3:$B$8').getValues();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
    lookupRange.push(range[i][0]);

  var index = lookupRange.indexOf(lookup);
  if (index == -1) {
    // implicit no-op
  }
  else {
    var link = range[index][2]
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(link);
    sheet.showSheet();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up an [installable trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) This allows the script to run with authorization, whereas normally "onOpen()" is run as a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). Since Simple Triggers can't authorize as users, you'll never get an email address.

The simplest solution is to set testGetEmail() to be run on open. Do this within the Script Editor by choosing Resources > Current Project's Triggers in the menu. Then click "No triggers set up. Click here to add one now." Finally, set up your trigger:

1. Choose your function's name (testGetEmail) from  the first dropdown under "Run."
2. Choose "From spreadsheet" in the second dropdown under "Events."
3. Choose "On Open" in the third dropdown.

Then test to be sure I didn't commit a typo :-)

Comment: Thanks @jjjjoe your suggestion worked. I am new to this and still learning my way around. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I cant seem to review your suggested edits. Sorry. My reputation will not allow me as of the moment. That worked too..Thank you.

Comment: No problem; it looks like somebody approved my edits. I made the edits in a local editor because I was looking for logic problems, but it's good that somebody approved them :-)